# I've rented a subnet and assigned the IPs to my server. Why aren't they working?

Tags: networking, server, proxy, ip, ip-address

like I said I've rented a subnet and I've set them up with a host on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. I was told I need to change the interfaces file to get the new IP addresses to work, I have tried this and the file looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 185.116.239.139
netmask 255.255.255.248

eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 185.137.131.0
netmask 255.255.255.248


eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 185.137.131.1
netmask 255.255.255.248


eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
address 185.137.131.2
netmask 255.255.255.248


eth0:4
iface eth0:4 inet static
address 185.137.131.3
netmask 255.255.255.248
```

all the way up to 255 but for some reason none of the IPs are working. Every time that I reset the server the interfaces file resets to the default.

I'm new to all of this so any help would be appreciated.

Also if it makes a difference I am trying to use the IPs to create proxies using Squid.

Comment: You've 'rented' a subnet; have you made sure that the IPs are actually *routed* to the system at the datacenter or VPS provider?  Also, if you have a /24, `.0` and `.255` are unusable.  You also don't have a route set up according to your configuraiton - you usually need a 'gateway' that goes to the Internet (usually `.1`).

Comment: Yes that's all been done, I didn't know that they were unusable I'll miss those out out then.

I have this listed as the gateway 185.116.239.137, do I need that for every IP and so would I need to change it to a .1 then? I just copied it from the default interfaces file.

Comment: Did your ISP not tell you what netmask and gateway to use? Your netmask of 255.255.255.248 is wrong for sure. It has to be at least 255.255.255.0, maybe even broader. Your use of 185.116.239.139 makes no sense at all, as I think eth0 should be on the same sub-net as your aliased interfaces.

Comment: Nope they didn't, I'll try and contact them about it now, for the net mask I just copied the one that I found in the default interfaces file and the same with 185.116.239.139, that's the servers default IP.

Comment: You probably also need dns-nameservers.

Comment: I've managed to get the IPs up but now I'm running into an error where whenever I try to connect to them I get timed out. I can't ping them either.

Comment: Edit your question with your updated interfaces file, and the information you got from your ISP.

Comment: I seem to be able to ping your IP addresses now. I couldn't a few hours ago. Please update us.